# How to send scheduled message using telebot python

Tags: python, py-telegram-bot-api

In telegram client you can send a scheduled message and select a time at which it will be sent. Is there a way to do that using python Telebot library and not keep the script running and checking time manually?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use modules like [apscheduler](https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler)

example usage:

```
import telebot
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

sched = BlockingScheduler()
bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')

def my_interval_job():
    bot.send_message("WARNERSTARK", "Goodmorning. its 6am!")
    ... # do more at 6 am
    

sched.add_job(my_interval_job, trigger="cron", hour=6)
sched.start()
```

The above example sends a message to user at 6 am.

Read [More](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)